# Cordova app with storage

Tags: cordova

just to get some advise from the pros. I'd like to build something similar to Bible application which initially has lot of data already in the storage. What would be a good way & best practice to store those data in Cordova/Phonegap world?

Of course, I would like to store additional data along with the large dataset and it is good to have search capabilities as well.

Comment: You have access to HTML5 localStorage with cordova. Just be aware there's a 2gb size limit on iOS apps. this may also help with accessing native SDKs http://ngcordova.com/docs/ Other than that, this question is really broad.

Comment: localstorage is too limited. but seems websql might be a good solution. However, does that mean when installing the app, or initial load of application, i need to insert data to websql from some source? (or parse from a file???)